# Error Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.String.equals(java.lang.Object)'

Tags: java, android, firebase

Podrían ayúdame a solucionar el error? He estado revisando mi código muchas veces y aun no lo encuentro. el error que envía `Android Studio` es:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method
>   'boolean java.lang.String.equals(java.lang.Object)' on a null object
>   reference

He revisado la sintaxis de los métodos y no encuentro el problema. el error esta en estos métodos.

```
private void mensajeVisto() {
    userRefVisto = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Chats");
    vistoListener = userRefVisto.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
       for (DataSnapshot ds: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
           ModeloChat chat = ds.getValue(ModeloChat.class);
           if (chat.getRecibido().equals(miUID) && chat.getEnviado().equals(suUID)){

               HashMap<String, Object> seVioHashMap = new HashMap<>();
               seVioHashMap.put("Visto", true);
               ds.getRef().updateChildren(seVioHashMap);
           }
       }
   }

   @Override
   public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

   }
});

}


private void mensajeLeido() {
    chatList = new ArrayList<>();
    DatabaseReference dbRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Chats");

    dbRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            chatList.clear();

            for (DataSnapshot ds: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                ModeloChat chat = ds.getValue(ModeloChat.class);

                if (chat.getRecibido().equals(miUID) && chat.getEnviado().equals(suUID) ||
                        chat.getRecibido().equals(suUID) && chat.getEnviado().equals(miUID)){
                    chatList.add(chat);

                }
                    adaptadorChat = new AdaptadorChat(ChatActivity.this, chatList, suImagen);
                adaptadorChat.notifyDataSetChanged();

                recyclerView.setAdapter(adaptadorChat);
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {


        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Agrega la validacion de que el obj chat no sea nulo para ejecutar los if donde comparas tus strings de la siguiente manera:

```
if (chat != null){
if (chat.getRecibido().equals(miUID) && chat.getEnviado().equals(suUID)){

               HashMap<String, Object> seVioHashMap = new HashMap<>();
               seVioHashMap.put("Visto", true);
               ds.getRef().updateChildren(seVioHashMap);
           }
}



if (chat != null){
if (chat.getRecibido().equals(miUID) && chat.getEnviado().equals(suUID) ||
                        chat.getRecibido().equals(suUID) && chat.getEnviado().equals(miUID)){
                    chatList.add(chat);

                }
}
```